# xorg pointer "partially" acts as if button one depressed when not

Tags: gnome, mouse, xinput

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04 with Gnome on two Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Tablets. Every so often I find my pointer partially acting as if the button 1 is pressed even though it is not.  I say "partially" because some pointer functions do not behave this way and others do.  For example selecting icons on the desktop behaves normally: the pointer moves and only when I press and hold button one can I drag and select a rectangle.  But in Nautilus if I click on a folder I have placed in the "bookmarks", the lower region of left hand subwindow, and then release the mouse button, when I move the mouse it shows that I am trying to reorder the bookmark and will not release it until I click and release the icon a second time.  The normal action for reordering is click and do not release the mouse button. Something similar happens in Calibre:  If I left click on one of my ebooks in the list of all ebooks and then release the mouse button, when I move the mouse up or down it starts selecting a range of my ebooks.  Again the normal action to do this it to press and hold the mouse button.

It is application dependent: in Libreoffice for example, the mouse does not select a range of cells after I release the mouse button.  It is not hardware dependent: when the behaviour is happening,  it happens for any mouse I plug in. If I logout and log back in again (or restart the computer) the pointer reverts to the correct behaviour.  When it is happening in my x-session it does not happen if I switch users to another account on the machine, but it is still happening in my x-session when I return.

I have tried --list-props on my various xinput devices to see if I can find anything unusual but I am not sure what to look for and it is not tied to a single device so I am not sure this is where I would find the issue.

Comment: why has it not occured to you that your mouse may be flaky?

Comment: It is hardware independent.  If the situation is happening, then it happens with every mouse I try to use in addition to built in trackpad and trackpoint.  It also happens on two different laptops that I use with different pointing devices.

Comment: It also only behaves in this way with certain applications, if all the various mouse hardwares were the problem, then I would expect the problematic behaviour in every application.

Comment: Since you are on a tablet, does your list-props show a touchscreen, and do you touch the screen?  Perhaps it modifies interpretation of the mouse behaviour. Also, look at accessibility options: some of these might be getting switched on automatically by detecting long-presses on certain keys or buttons, or certain combinations of them.

Comment: @meuh, this is a good idea.  Both my tablets have a touch screen.  I am interested if this could be the case.  Have you seen any other discussions on StackExchange with people experiencing touchscreen modifying mouse behaviours?  I would like to read more.   I recently rebooted so everything is behaving normally right now so I will dump xinput --list-props and --query-state for all my pointers to files and compare them the next time the behaviour starts.  Are there other data you recommend collecting besides xinput?

Comment: I don't know gnome, but perhaps a `gsettings list-recursively` dump will show a difference if done before and after the behaviour change.